# Не получается реализовать привязку DataGrid к свойству ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

Используется паттерн MVVM. База данных обновляется при добавлении строки. Коллекция также содержит измененные или добавленные строки, но DataGrid не обновляется.

Model

```
namespace Terminal_Forts_ММВБ.Model
{
    public class PortfelStrateg : ViewModelINPC
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get => id; set
            {
                if (id != value)
                {
                    _ = SetField(ref id, value);
                }
            }
        }

        private string portfel;
        public string Portfel
        {
            get => portfel; set
            {
                if (portfel != value)
                {
                    _ = SetField(ref portfel, value);
                }
            }
        }

        private string instrument;
        public string Instrument
        {
            get => instrument; set
            {
                if (instrument != value)
                {
                    _ = SetField(ref instrument, value);
                }
            }
        }
        
        private double zena_tek;
        public double Zena_tek
        {
            get => zena_tek; set
            {
                if (zena_tek != value)
                {
                    _ = SetField(ref zena_tek, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ViewModelINPC : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```
namespace Terminal_Forts_ММВБ.Model
{
    public static class DataWorker
    {
     public static ObservableCollection<PortfelStrateg> GetAllPortfelStrategs()
        {
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
ObservableCollection<PortfelStrateg> portfelStrategsObservable = new ObservableCollection<PortfelStrateg>();
                var result = db.PortfelStrategs.ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    portfelStrategsObservable.Add(result[i]);
                }
                return portfelStrategsObservable;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace Terminal_Forts_ММВБ.ViewModel
{
    public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelINPC
    {
        #region Вывести весь список (binding на таблицы)
        //Таблица PortfelStrateg
        private ObservableCollection<PortfelStrateg> allPortfelStrategs = DataWorker.GetAllPortfelStrategs();
        public ObservableCollection<PortfelStrateg> AllPortfelStrategs
        {
            get => allPortfelStrategs;
            set
            {
                if (allPortfelStrategs != value)
                {
                    _ = SetField(ref allPortfelStrategs, value);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

      #region Метод редактирования dataGridPortfelStrateg по событию колбэка
      public void EditDataGridPortfelStrategMetodEvent()
      {
        //Вычисления и запись в базу данных
        AllPortfelStrategs = DataWorker.GetAllPortfelStrategs();
      }
    }
}
```

View

```
namespace Terminal_Forts_ММВБ.View
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
private readonly ApplicationViewModel viewModel = new ApplicationViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;            
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Terminal_Forts_ММВБ.ViewModel"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    x:Class="Terminal_Forts_ММВБ.View.MainWindow"        
       mc:Ignorable="d"
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:ApplicationViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AllPortfelStrategs}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Portfel}"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Instrument}"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding ="{Binding Zena_tek}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: ObservableCollection и так умеет уведомлять view о своих изменениях и в ее сеттере не нужен метод OnPropertyChanged("AllPortfelStrategs"). Чтобы изменения коллекции отобразились во view нужно либо вызвать у этой коллекции методы Add(); Remove(); или изменить какой-либо элемент коллекции обратившись к нему по индексу. Ни одного из этих способов изменения коллекции у вас в VM нет. Поэтому view не отображает изменения коллекции

Comment: Вызов метода: AllPortfelStrategs.Add() обращается к геттору коллекции. Коллекция заполняется, а DataGrid при этом вообще не заполняется. К сеттору идет обращение при: AllPortfelStrategs = portfelStrategsObservable;  эффект тот же. DataGrid получается обновить только так: AllPortfelStrategsDataGrid.DataContext = AllPortfelStrategs;   Xaml: ItemsSource="{Binding }".  Но при частом обновлении датаконтекста не возможно работать с таблицей.

Comment: Где INPC у `AllPortfelStrategs`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Вы об этом: OnPropertyChanged("AllPortfelStrategs") в сеттере коллекции?

Comment: Да. Посмотрел историю вопроса, и увидел, что вы удалили, также увидел первый комментарий, где говорят "не нужен". Человек явно перепутал изменение свойства и изменение коллекции, это два совершенно разных действия, за которые отвечают два совершенно разных интерфейса. Смотрите.. Когда вы пишете `.Add()` или любой другой метод коллекции - это идет изменение коллекции, за это отвечает `INotifyCollectionChanged`, который по умолчанию есть в `ObservableCollection` и в `BindingList`, всем остальным коллекциям нужно реализовывать этот интерфейс для обновления UI.

Comment: Когда вы делаете `mySuperProperty = new MySuperType();` или `MySuperProperty = "Привет мир!";` - это идет изменения свойства, и за то, чтобы UI обновил данные свойства, отвечает уже `INotifyPropertyChanged`, совсем другой интерфейс. Если у вас свойство в ходе работы приложения меняет свое значение, то вы обязаны сделать вызов метода в сеттере (`set`) свойства. В вашем случае это `OnPropertyChanged("AllPortfelStrategs")`, да.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за комментарий. Это навело на мысль проверить значение PropertyChanged при вызове из set и оно всегда Null, поэтому не происходит изменения в UI. Почему Null, если выполняется условие изменения значения свойств коллекции в сеттере?

Comment: Он `NULL` тогда, когда нет подписчиков на событие. У вас они должны быть, если только вы `DataContext` не переопределяете где либо повторно, и то не факт. Вообще, INPC обычно выносят в отдельный класс, в котором и делают проверки на изменение свойства, и т.д., получают нечто [такое](https://pastebin.com/L37vahp6). Пройдитесь отладкой, посмотрите, `OnPropertyChanged("AllPortfelStrategs")` вообще вызывается?

Comment: Вообще, у вас в вопросе куча мусора, на подобии `readonly ApplicationViewModel viewModel = new ApplicationViewModel();`, который не используется где либо, или например `public static DataGrid AllPortfelStrategsDataGrid;`, в XAML также каша, с кучей лишних свойств. Советую избавиться от лишнего, так будет и вам, и мне более понятней что и как творится в коде. Также, у вас есть ряд нарушений MVVM, например в чистом MVVM не используют события по типу `Click="MenuItem_Click"`, также в нем не используют `x:Name`, ну и `static DataGrid` - это View слой в ViewModel, что является грубым нарушением.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Сейчас в сеттере вызывается: SetField(ref allPortfelStrategs, value); и далее из класса интерфейса INPC вызывается: OnPropertyChanged("AllPortfelStrategs"), но PropertyChanged по прежнему Null. DataContext задан один раз. Интерфейс INPC реализует подписку на событие PropertyChanged, или необходимо дополнительно подписываться?

Comment: `if (allPortfelStrategs != value)` уберите, это лишнее. А так, если не работает, то делайте тогда [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), на чистом WPF проекте, чтоб его мог воспроизвести я и другие участники SO. Без него мы в тупике.

Comment: Если убрать проверку на Null, в исключении требуется указать экземпляр объекта, если я правильно понимаю, нужно дополнительно подписаться на событие PropertyChanged. Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Я вам дал пример полноценной реализации INPC, со всеми проверками, а также дал пример свойства, которое вызывает INPC. Все, кроме этого ничего больше в вашем коде быть не должно, вообще ничего. Если то, что я кинул вы сделали, и это не помогло, то повторю - воспроизводящий пример, который я смогу запустить у себя и лично проверить что там не так. Без этого, мы с вами в тупике, ибо если я сделаю чистый WPF проект, скопирую код, который дал вам, привяжу в XAML, и попробую изменить, то все будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос по реализации Binding решен. Изменения по переопределению DataContext в View и Xaml, а также установил пакет NuGet System.Reflection.